# Create new instance of passed Class.class argument

Tags: java, oop, class

Let's say that I have a function that has the purpose of creating a new instance of any specified class, and then returning it. Perhaps something like this:

```
public static <T> Class<T> forgeClass(Class<T> classReference) {

    return new classReference.getClass();

}
```

Usage (with `Employee` class):

```
Employee foo = forgeClass(Employee.class); // new Employee instance
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Fair warning: there isn't necessarily going to be a solution in any general case.  Some classes are deliberately designed so that they can't be instantiated.  Some classes are deliberately designed so that they can only be instantiated once.  You may be breaking that class's assumptions and screwing up its logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use [`Class.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29);

```
public static <T> T forge(final Class<T> type)
    throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  return type.newInstance();
}
```

Use as follows...

```
final Employee employee = forge(Employee.class);
```

In case you want to use a more complex initialization routine, e.g. `Employee(String name)`, you should use [`Class.getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29), followed by [`Constructor.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29).

```
final Constructor ctor = Employee.class.getConstructor(String.class);
final Employee employee = ctor.newInstance("Steve");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method and the return type of your method should be `T` instead of `Class<T>`.

```
public static <T> T forgeClass(Class<T> classReference) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return classReference.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Whoever down voted please care to leave an explanation. That would be helpful so that I could improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

```
Class<?> yourClass;
return yourClass.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Class.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) is exactly what you need:

```
public static <T> T forgeClass(Class<T> classReference) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return classReference.newInstance();
}
```

If you want to pass arguments to a constructor you have to use [`java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html):

```
public static <T> T forgeClass(Class<T> classReference, Object... constructorArguments)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException,
        NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?>[] argumentTypes = new Class<?>[constructorArguments.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < constructorArguments.length; i++)
        argumentTypes[i] = constructorArguments[i].getClass();
    Constructor<T> ctor = classReference.getConstructor(argumentTypes);
    return ctor.newInstance(constructorArguments);
}
```

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments this code will not work if you pass a subclass in the arguments

Comment: What happens if you have `class Bar extends Foo { }` and a constructor that takes `Foo`, but you pass `Bar`? I'll give you a hint: your code won't work. Expect a `NoSuchMethodException`. What you're doing is not enough. You need to check [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) or [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)).